# laravel echo server , redis

Tags: redis, laravel-5.4, laravel-echo

i have a problem with remote connections.

my vhost is : redis.test

i added this on blade file:

```
<script src="//redis.test:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

.env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=redis.test
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

echo configuration

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'socket.io',
   host: 'http://redis.test:6001'
});
```

laravel-exho-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "http://redis.test",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "f27485125ac2627f",
            "key": "6328e672f42cbf4cba1de3da215ec41a"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "redis.test"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "redis.test",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": ""
}
```

it works when i try to broadcast with a local connection (2 browsers - same pc), but when i try to send a "message" from other pc on lan network (192.168.1.50) i have this error

```
GET: http://redis.test:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js net::err_connection_refused

[vue_warn] error in created hook
```

how ca i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a firewall issue as I can see, try to open redis port in the firewall